# Best usage of indexes and primary key on joined and filtered data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables with the exact same number of rows and the same non-repeated id. Because the data comes from 2 sources I want to keep it 2 tables and not combine it. I assume the best approach would be to leave the unique id as the primary key and join on it?

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA primary key = tableB primary key
```

The data is used by an application that force the user to select 1 or many values from 5 drop downs in cascading order:

1. select 1 or many values from tableA column1.
2. select 1 or many values from tableA column2 but filtered from the first filter.
3. select 1 or many values from tableA column3 but filtered from the second filter which in turn is filtered from the first filter.

For example:

| pk | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Doe | Jane | 2022-01 |
| 234 | Doe | Jane | 2021-12 |
| 345 | Doe | John | 2022-03 |
| 456 | Jones | Mary | 2022-04 |

Selecting "Doe" from column1 would limit the second filter to ("Jane","John"). And selecting "Jane" from column2 would filter column3 to ("2022-01","2021-12")

And last part of the question;

The application have 3 selection options for column3:

- picking the exact value (for example "2022-01") or picking the year ("2022") or picking the quarter that the month falls into ("Q1", which equates in "01","02","03").
- What would be the best usage of indexes `AND`/`OR` additional columns for this scenario?

Volume of data would be 20-100 million rows.
Each filter is in the range of 5-25 distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Postgres do you operate?

The volume you state is rather daunting for such a use case of populating drop-down boxes using live data for a PG db.

No kidding, it's possible, Kibana/Elastic has even a filter widget that works exactly this way for instance.

My guess is you may consider storing the different combinations of search columns in another table simply to speed up populating the dropboxes. You can achieve that with triggers on the two main tables. So instead of additional columns/indexes you may end with an additional table ;)

Regarding indexing strategy and given the hints you stated (AND/OR), I'd say there's no silver bullet. Index the columns that will be queried the most often.

Index each column individually because Postgres starting from 11 IIRC can combine multiple indexes to answer conjunctive/disjunctive formulas in WHERE clauses.

Hope this helps

Comment: Version is 12.3. I assume with the third table you recommend it would be created from SELECT DISTINCT columnA, columnB, columnC....  ? Is it worthwile having a primary key on this table, and if so, what would it be? A sequence number or perhaps a concat of all the columns?

Comment: I don't think this utility table needs a PK but if you want to go for it, make the PK span all the columns. And yes, initialize and populate that table with CTAS as you say and keep it in sync with triggers. On second though, you may need a PK spanning all the columns to check whether you need to update/insert a row from the trigger handler.